# UITableViewController Table Header Add a UIButton with Autolayout Constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I try to add a UIButton to a UITableHeaderFooterView.

It seems that I can only use specific CGRect frame to pin its position and size in code (<-- did a lot of search on StackOverFlow). And the position is very hard to control, always flying around.

```
UIButton *scanQRCodeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
scanQRCodeButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 5.0f, 320.0f, 44.0f);
scanQRCodeButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[scanQRCodeButton setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];    
[cell addSubview:scanQRCodeButton];
```

But what I really want is to use "constraints" like centerX, centerY and proportional width to make it adaptive to different screen size. Then the problem comes with the part "constraintWithItems":

Get the headerView from UITableView:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    static NSString *headerReuseIdentifier = @"TableViewSectionHeaderViewIdentifier";

    // Reuse the instance that was created in viewDidLoad, or make a new one if not enough.
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *headerView = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:headerReuseIdentifier];
    if (headerView == nil) {
        [tableView registerClass:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class] forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:@"TableViewSectionHeaderViewIdentifier"];
        headerView = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"TableViewSectionHeaderViewIdentifier"];
    }

    headerView.textLabel.text = @"MISSION";
    headerView.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Create the UIButton on top of the headerView in the same block as above:

```
UIButton *goBack = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [goBack setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Back"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [goBack addTarget:self
           action:@selector(back:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [headerView addSubview:goBack];
```

Then set the constraints and return the headerView:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                  constraintWithItem:headerView.goBack
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:self.view
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                  multiplier:0.5
                                  constant:0];
    [headerView addConstraint:constraint];
    return headerView;
```

Problem: when I say "headerView.goBack" in "constraintWithItem", the compiler warns me that "Property goBack not found on object of type UITableHeaderFooterView".

**Update 1**

From Natarajan's answer, I try to do this now:

```
    headerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    goBack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    NSDictionary *metrics   = @{ @"width"           :   @(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) / 10) };
    [headerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[goBack]|" options:0 metrics:metrics   views:@{@"goBack":goBack}]];
    [headerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[goBack]|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:@{@"goBack":goBack}]];
```

Current Problem: The "metrics" part does not work. I want to have proportional width to the headerView or tableView instead of fixed numbers. Should I use "self.view.frame" (also tried self.tableView.frame)?

**Update 2**

There is also a problem with the headerView now. If I use "headerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;", I also need to manually set headerView's position. However, with the following code, headerView can still not be set properly. I tried to add it to tableView first and set it the same way as UIButton but it couldn't work the same way.

```
[headerView addSubview:goBack];
[tableView addSubview:headerView];

headerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
goBack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

[headerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[goBack(40.0)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"goBack":goBack}]];
[headerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[goBack(40.0)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"goBack":goBack}]];
[tableView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[headerView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"headerView":headerView}]];
[tableView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[headerView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"headerView":headerView}]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think "goBack" can't accessed as headerView property. Try to find it.

```
    for (UIView *view in headerView.contentView.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            //found button
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Complier warning is correct as `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` doesn't have the property named "goBack" which you have just added as a subview of `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`. So Just try to pass the "goBack" button in your constraint code as like below.

To set goBack button fully occupied on HeaderView:

```
[headerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[goBack]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"goBack":goBack}]];

[headerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[goBack]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"goBack":goBack}]];
```

To set  goBack button for specific width and height:

```
[headerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[goBack(40.0)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"goBack":goBack}]];

[headerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[goBack(30.0)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"goBack":goBack}]];
```

Note: Before adding constraint don't forgot to set the `headerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;` and `goBack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;`

Comment: Thx! Please see my latest Update 1: I try to have proportional width instead.

Comment: There is also a problem with the headerView now. If I use "headerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;", I also need to manually set headerView's position. However, with the following code, headerView can still not be set properly. I tried to add it to tableView first and set it the same way as UIButton but it couldn't work the same way.

Comment: I want to have proportional width to the headerView or tableView instead of fixed numbers. I use "self.view.frame" (also tried self.tableView.frame) in "metrics" but both of them can not work properly.